# Boost Fiber on OS X

Tags: macos, c++14, boost-thread, lld

I'm trying to get boost fiber up and running on os x, and I'm having quite a few issues.  First, fiber won't compile with Apple clang because of the use of `thread_local` which Apple does not support (according to what I found online, they think they can implement it better than standard llvm and don't want to introduce it only to break ABI later).

So instead, I tried using gcc-5 installed through homebrew. After a bit of screwing around with boost build I managed to get fiber to build, and I can link sample programs successfully, but they seg fault.

Then I figured I'd give current llvm a try, since it has thread_local support, and I can again get boost fiber to build fine, but now I'm getting issues because the os x linker doesn't seem to handle thread local properly either!  I would post the exact error, but my power is out.  I did actually get it to link though with a couple changes to fiber, but the sample program failed again.

So the question is, how can I make this happen? Is there any way to get another linker working to produce os x executables for me? Llvm comes with another linker called lld, but I don't think it does what I'm after.

I think if I absolutely had to, I could go through fiber and boost context replacing all thread_local with boost::thread_specific_ptr, but I'm not sure how deep that rabbit hole goes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: no code? no debugging, backtraces; no link to [Boost Fiber](https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber) even? Seems you're betting on someone doing the exact same thing and being psychic about what you're doing "wrong", specifically

Comment: As I said, my power went out. I will update the question when I have access to my computer. Until then I was hoping for some helpful suggestions....